# How do I prevent auto-mounting of ext2 partition on OSX?

Tags: htc-desire, macos, ext2

I've created a 512Mb partition on my HTC Desire's (running LeeDroid) SD card to store apps.
When I used Windows, I'd never had a problem with this partition becoming read-only, unreadable or corrupted.

Since I switched to a Mac, this partition got corrupted several times. Somehow, I thought it was LeeDroid's fault, and didn't blame it on the Mac.

I installed Cyanogenmod on the Desire to overcome this problem, but the ext2 partition on the card still kept getting corrupted. I read on the [Cyanogen's forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/25894-use-sd-as-primary-storage/page__view__findpost__p__211336) that Linux and OSX automatically mount the ext2 partition when the phone is plugged in, causing the partition to become corrupted, and then this made sense.

Question: Is is possible to prevent OSX from automatically mounting the ext2 partition on Android phone's SD card?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Linux buff but [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060930150059172) Macworld article seems promising assuming you know the UUID for the volume and don't mind working from the terminal. The article wisely recommends backing up the volume before messing around too much.

Also... Googling for Android+phone+UUID is returning links which are related to programming. Perhaps retrieving the UUID from an Android phone is a separate question for this problem.